# "meaningless for both of us" vs. "meaningless for either of us"

Tags: grammar, either-any

I wonder if I should rephrase the sentence "These efforts are not meaningful for either of us" into

1) "These efforts are meaningless for either of us"

or

2) "These efforts are meaningless for both of us"

Both sound weird to me. I think my main question is when "meaningless" has a negative concept, does it count as a negation word in the sentence?

Comment: What was your research, and what did it indicate?

Comment: Not meaningful to me is more subtle that meaningless.